# import Spacy on RPI in Pycharm and other IDE gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, spacy

I successfully installed Spacy using `pip install spacy` and alternatively through Pycharms virtual env, but when I `import spacy` in my program it's giving me the following error;

```
    home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python /home/pi/PycharmProjects/testSpeech/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/testSpeech/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/train.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, linear_decay
  File "thinc/neural/optimizers.pyx", line 14, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "thinc/neural/ops.pyx", line 36, in init thinc.neural.ops
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blis/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cy import init
ImportError: /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blis/cy.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_load_8

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Where do you run the import? In the console? Via a configuration set in Pycharm?
Make sure your Python interpreter is set properly in Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter as well as in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console as well as in any configuration from which you would run this piece of code

Comment: Also, give a try to File -> Invalidate Cache and restart if the above is properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some problem while loading some library which was some prerequisite for spacy.

The problem was solved by calling the file via terminal with the following command;

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python3 main.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a 32-bit OS? Instead, you will need a 64-bit OS with 64-bit python for spaCy v2, e.g.: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2020-08-24/

As of spacy v2.3.5 you should be able to install spacy in a venv for linux aarch64 with:

```sh
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
pip install spacy
```

Alternatively, there are binary linux aarch64 packages on conda-forge. There's a linux aarch64 miniforge installer and the install command would be `conda install spacy`. If you're not using the miniforge installer, then you need to add `-c conda-forge` or otherwise add the conda-forge channel.

See: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/6638